# Python code to import OSM data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pyqgis, import

I am trying to automize the workflow: import osm
data and select by a special tag. 
I have to do this steps a lot of time with different parameters and updated data.

A Solution could be a python script using PyQGIS or using the Graphical modeler. 
But in both cases I could not finde the tools to import OSM Data
as pythoncode or within the Graphical modeler in qgis.

The manual workflow is discribed in this great tutorial:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you need to use Python? There are command line tools for downloading OSM extracts.

Comment: No there's no need to use Python, but I don't need to automate the download I need the tools to import osm data in QGIS

Comment: What is the format of your OSM data ? Because Qgis can import a lot kind of data.

Comment: The format is: .osm

Answer (score 2):

Did you heard about QuickOSM it's a plugin which simplify the workflow for you. You can run a queries on specifics tags and stores it. Also it has the ability to build a graphical modeler with these tools. the code repo is [here](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM) (but I suggest you to install it with the Qgis plugin manager) and a demo video [here](https://vimeo.com/108737868). Hope it helps you.